# How to click a button to add a value to an array and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently stuck on trying to use an onclick button to push a value into an array.

```
let display = document.getElementById('screen');
let results = [];
display.innerHTML = results[0];

$(document).ready(() => {

  $('.one').click(function() {
    results.push(1);
  });

})
```

I am trying to push 1 into the array when the button is pushed, then display it. However, my current code does not push the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work, but the line that shows the results must be inside of the `click` callback. **As it is now, the display gets updated just once, before the click happens.**

Also, JQuery deprecated "shortcut" event methods (`.click()`) a while back and recommends the use of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Lastly, [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) has performance and security implications, so don't use `innerHTML` when the string in question doesn't contain any HTML. Instead, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). But, because you are already using JQuery, you can use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```js
// If you are going to use JQuery, then use it.
// Here, we can get the element with an id of "screen"
// into a JQuery wrapped set object very easily.
// Naming the variable that will hold that JQuery object
// with a $ is a standard convention to remind you that 
// the variable holds a JQuery object and not a standard
// DOM object.
let $display = $('#screen');
let results = [];

// And, with JQuery, if you just pass a function directly 
// to JQuery, that function is automatically understood to
// be a document.ready callback
$(() => {
  $('.one').on("click" ,function() {
    results.push(1);
    $display.text(results[0]); // This must be in the callback to show the most up to date information
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="one" value="push">
<div id="screen"></div>
```

Comment: nice answer - but displaying results[0] on the click  simply displays the original value each time (ie - no matter the length of the array - it shows the value of the first item. If you use .unshift() instead of .push() then you will get the newest value since it wil be the first item in the results array. alternatively display the results[results.length-1] to show the last item added.

Comment: @gavgrif Yes, but it's not my code. I'm showing the OP how to make his/her code do what he/she intended.